# Как написать грамотней?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Подскажите, как правильно писать: "та, кого" или "та, какую"?
Например: "Обманула девушка, та, кого я полюбил".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В разговорной речи возможны оба варианта. Но оба имеют весьма ограниченную сферу применения. Вариант "та, кого", вызывает орфоэпические затруднения на почве несвободности образования форм от "та, кто".  В качестве замены (тоже разговорной, но более широкого примения) используется "та, что".
Вариант "та, какую" имеет другой оттенок смысла. Не личность, а качества: добрую, там или красивую.
Наконец, предлагаемый вариант "та, которую" безусловно нормативен, но в разговорной речи может вызвать впечатление книжности.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: Обманула девушка, та, которую я полюбил.

Comment: Безусловно, "та, кого" и "та, какую" могут употребляться в разговорной речи. Но вопрос был задан по поводу того, как правильно ПИСАТЬ, поэтому был предложен нормативный вариант.

Comment: Я подозреваю, что автор **пишет** стихи. Так что нормативность подобного рода тут не всегда аргумент.  
И самое главное, разговорная речь традиционно противопоставляется всё-таки книжной, а письменная - устной. Писать вполне можно и разговорной речью, а лирику - даже нужно.